# How do I get more frog treats?

Tags: flutter-starlight

I can feed my frog fireflies and other delicacies to get flowers so I can get better butterflies.

They seem to be pretty random, though. Is there any logic to when I get fireflies/frog treats, so I can ensure I have lots of flowers to attract the butterflies I want?

Comment: It also seems pretty random to feed fireflies to frogs to get flowers that bring butterflies. Also, what did the poor fireflies do to deserve to get eaten?